# WPF - Click on item in ListView

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the selected item of a listview by clicking or double clicking on it.

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="doelenContentPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,50,0" Width="Auto">

            <TextBlock Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="10,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248" Text="PickerUse"/>

            <ListView Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

for buttons I can just use the method Add_click ($window.rbImport.Add_Click({ ) on an item in WPF but this does not exist on listview. How can I set this programmatically without changing the WPF itself?
I tried $window.listview but when I choose a mouse method it is telling me that this method does not exist:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Controls.ListView] does not contain a method named 'MouseDoubleClicked'
```

Thanks

Comment: For me this is working: $WPFListView.Add_MouseDoubleClick({Write-Host "Double clicked"})

Comment: Thats it. I thought I tested it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was:

```
 $WPFListView.Add_MouseDoubleClick({Write-Host "Double clicked"})
```